# Go Viper return value of env variable only if exists

Tags: go

Given the following sample code

```golang
import "github.com/spf13/viper"

const EnvPort = "PORT"

func init() {
    viper.AutomaticEnv()
}

func GetPort() int {
    viper.SetDefault(EnvPort, 8080)
    port := viper.GetInt(EnvPort)

    return port
}
```

Using `GetPort` always returns a port. But in my case I only want to return a port if the field exists. I'm basically looking for code like this

```golang
func GetPortIfExists() (bool, int) {
    portFieldExists := viper.IsSet(EnvPort)

    if !portFieldExists {
        return false, 0
    }

    return true, viper.GetInt(EnvPort)
}
```

I tested the code with this line above `os.Setenv(EnvPort, "8080")` but unfortunately `portFieldExists` returns false. So maybe `viper.IsSet` is not the function I'm looking for.

What is the correct way to check if the env variable exists with a value?

Comment: This? Viper bug [#397](https://github.com/spf13/viper/issues/397).

Answer (score 0):

Viper aims to abstract you from config sources. Its `IsSet` function does not work in terms of "env variables" or "lines in config files." It checks Viper's parameters that can go from any source. So, it is unsafe to count on viper to check env vars for existence because other sources can change the result. But Viper has the [debug](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/viper#Debug) function that shows sources for each parameter.

The primary Go way to check if the env var exists is `os.LookupEnv()`

If you are interested mainly in environment variables and not in mixing configs from a few sources, try specialized lib for loading configurations from  env variables, like [envconfig](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig)

Comment: Just checked how to distinguish "no var" from "empty value" cases with envconfig. It could be tricky too. Simple case: set the default value. More complex case: envconfig.Decoder